# Confused about Node order rules (synchronous/asynchronous)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, if-statement, asynchronous

My example is a simple HTTP server:

```
http.createServer((req, res) => {
  if(req.method === `GET`){

    if(req.headers.cookie === undefined){
      let x = 1
      let y = 2
      let z = 30
    }
    else{
      let x = 10
      let y = 20
      let z = 3
    }

    switch(req.url){

      case `/`:

        // >>>> I need the appropriate variables here for the same client <<<<

        break

      case `/page`:

        // >>>> or here <<<<

        break

      default:
        res.statusCode = 404
        res.end(`Error 404`)
    }
  }
}).listen(3000)
```

When a client connects, the variables are defined by whether or not the client has a cookie. But what if multiple clients connect at almost the same time? How does Node handle that?

Is it possible for the clients to get mixed up variables, because the if/else statement happens before the switch? Should I instead place 2 copies of the switch in each of the if/else parts?

Or is there no difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each connection will be it's own "stack" in Node, so they will be independent. Really, each connection will have it's own copy/instance of the `req` object, and the code you write is only working on that `req` object. All other `req` objects that exist are their own stack.

The code will happen in order, so you are safe to have the if/else before the switch.